# Is it possible to check email from a Unity program?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, email

I've seen several posts/tutorials showing how to send email from a Unity program, but I'd like to find out how to retrieve email from a Unity program without using a PHP script. What libraries would be needed? Are there examples of how to use it?
I'm now using Visual studio with Unity, but because of the limitations of Unity c#, I'm not sure if it would work.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter that you use Unity? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can search github or asset store for a C# POP or IMAP client. I found this one.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit